# How to remove part of file between two line delimiter values in Scala Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have text as below,

```
TIME STAMP1 
   A1200 EVENT START
   EVENT NAME          = DOS
   EVENT_INS       = 1
   EVENT_ID       = 100  
   BUFFER             = 233355   
   FORMAT           = ATC
   LOC              = C:/User/data
;
TIME STAMP2 
   A1201 EVENT START
   EVENT NAME          = DOS
   EVENT_INS       = 0
   EVENT_ID       = 87  
   BUFFER             = 773355   
   FORMAT           = ETC
   LOC              = C:/User/data
;
```

how can I remove TIME STAMP2 based on A1201,need to remove from A1201 to ; using scala.A1201 sensor part will repeat at different location in the file. Wherever it comes, I need to remove from A1201 to ;..

How can I do with Scala Spark ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following simple solution

```
val rdd = sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("path to the text file")
rdd.map(x => x._2.replace("\n", "|*|").split(";").filter(!_.contains("A1201")).mkString(";").replace("|*|", "\n")+";")
```

where, 
 `wholeTextFiles` would read the file in `Tuple2` format with filename as first argument and text data as the second argument 
`x._2.replace("\n", "|*|")` replaces the line feeds with special character which is to be used later
`.split(";")` splits the text at `;` and forms array
`.filter(!_.contains("A1201"))` filters out all text from  `A1201` to `;` 
`.mkString(";").replace("|*|", "\n")+";"` converts the array of string to original format.

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Hello Ramesh Maharjan,great perfect...working for the purpose...I will try it in parse mechanism and update....thank you

Comment: Hello Ramesh, After convert to dataframe,it shows only one row with TIME STAMP1 .val rdd2 = rdd1.toDF() //rdd1 is the RDD String from parsing rdd2.show(20,false)....... What may the mistake on this

Comment: First I need to understand how did you form the dataframe. Can you ask another question with full detail on how you formed the dataframe and your issue? In the mean time, if this answer helped you then you can accept it and upvote if possible

Comment: thank you ramesh.I have only one file.The above same spilit method,how can I do using sc.textFile().I need two columns with the val1 and val2.for example, EVENT NAME,DOS and EVENT_INS, 1 etc.Here I need to convert column in dataframe based on seperated by ,as elimiter....so, col1contains EVENT NAME and col2 contains DOS in spark dataframe model.But when I try to convert as dataframe,all string comes as first row.But when I used sc.textFile() method, each value1 and value 2 comes as seperate column in dataframe model..I used .How to upvote .def I will do..val dataDF = rdd1.toDS(); dataDF.show()

Comment: val dataDF data,key pair is solved...thank you.

Comment: great to hear that @user680288

Comment: yes, now solved the issue.